# How to open a JFrame that was previously hidden from another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, instances

I have 2 frames and in the first one, I press a button to go to the other and then I hide the frame with:

```
frame1.this.hide();
```

How can I set that frame visible without creating a new one?

I know that I can make an instance to open a new frame1 from the frame2 but I want to "unhide" the first one when I press a button in the second JFrame.

Hope anybody know how to do this?

Comment: 1. `i want to "unhide" the first one when i press a button in the second JFrame.` - by creating Jframes Object as variable, 2. `I know that i can make an instance to open a new frame1 from the frame2 but` - you want to read Oracle tutorial - How to use CardLayout

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have to do is when creating Frame 2 . you have to pass same reference of Frame 1 then inside frame 2 you can change the viability of Frame 1